# Fetch Sol:r JSON with $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, solr

i want to fetch my JSON result from a sol:r request, but I always get an error back.

Heres the code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://' + url + '/solr/select',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'indent=on&version=2.2&q=name:pzn&start=0&rows=10&fl=name&qt=&wt=json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            var str = eval("("+data+")");
            $("#results").html('raw JSON: ' + str);
            },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
            }
    });
```

In my Log I can see, that the request has been handled by sol:r and sent an json back.
But all I get is an error like ' jQuery15204679577243202049_1316167632724 was not called'. Not very helpful but Firebug console says, that there's a invalid label in the response and just shows me the first JSON line '"responseHeader":{'

But I get the whole JSON back. The only thing that doesn't work, he just won't give it to me :D

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at this blog post [SOLR with JSONP with jQuery](http://skipperkongen.dk/2011/01/11/solr-with-jsonp-with-jquery/).The author shows a couple of different ways to call Solr with jQuery Ajax.

**Update:** How to handle result..

You can do the following to get access to the resulting raw JSON object...

```
$.getJSON(mySolrUrl, function(data) {
// data is bound to the result json
   alert("Found " + data.response.numFound + " documents.");
   alert("First document name field is: " + data.response.docs[0].name);
});
```

Plus also looking at your question again, I am not sure you want/need to do an ajax POST, as an ajax GET should return the same results. And the example I just added is only doing an ajax GET.

Comment: I already read this post, but it just returns me the following:  raw JSON: [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getJson function directly to get the json response from Solr.
Be sure you add the json.wrf=? parameter to the request URL, so the success method is called.

More @ http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolJSON#JSON_specific_parameters